# Is AndEngine a game engine?

Tags: android, game-engine, libgdx

I'm a newbie when it comes to Android Game Development and I have a few questions, that may be stupid or childish for some.

First, which is in the title, is AndEngine a game engine or a library? I've read different posts from the net which has different views and answers.

And, without using AndEngine, let's say I used the libgdx, will a newbie like me in Android Game Development create a decent game within 5-7 months?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: it's a game engine, which in essence is a framework specific to developing games, and a framework is a collection of libraries, imo in this instance the terminology is interchangeable. I wouldn't get too into the terminology, just grab the AndEngine and learn from examples and playing around with it.

Comment: That 5-7 months deadline depends on if you have any java and/or game development experience

Comment: I see. I'm planning to give android game development a shot for my thesis. Anyway, we're not allowed to use a game engine for it, so maybe I'll stick with libgdx, which is not an engine, right? 

And with my experience, I've made simulations with java. But using java for game development, well, it's something new.

Thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: Anything but asking your professor what explicitly you are allowed to use or not, is stupid. =)

If you want, you can call AndEngine an OpenGL abstraction layer... ;)

Comment: @Nicolas, That would be nice. But somehow I'm also eager to learn something from the lower levels. But we'll see about that. I like your idea though. :)

Comment: You can go low-level with AndEngine if you want to. =)

Comment: @NicolasGramlich , Yeah, I'm gonna try that. But anyway, was there any updates on the test project? I've seen AndEngine and tried it, but I've failed. And there are a lot of missing things in the test projects I've gotten. But as of now, I'm just starting the basics of game development based on Mario's book, so there's no need for me to rush for using such things. Well that's what I think? So as a pro, could you give me some tips or advice if you don't mind? =)

Answer (score 1):

As the site of [AndEngine](http://www.tov.be/campagnes.aspx?pageid=184156) says it is indeed an Android Game engine. For the second part of your question I don't have information or something like that so I'll let it over to other people to discuss about that.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit disappointing because we are not allowed to use a game engine for our thesis. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @jarenz funny as engine and library pretty much is the same in this case. Its a library no doubt. But its also an engine :)

Comment: @jarenz as Warpzit said, an engine is just a library, I think you are not able to use something like UDK or Unity which are complete enviroments. With AndEngine or libgdx there is a lot of work you have to put in: editors, tools, gamelogic, AI, ... All that is up to you.

Comment: @Moss, that's really confusing. Hahaha. But I get your point about UDK and Unity, I didn't really include those in my options. But still, with everything you've just said, I might consider AndEngine. Though it really bugs me. It's in the name, Android Engine. Haha :)

So UDK, Unity and AndEngines are all engines right?

Comment: @jarenz There is the point, the line between an engine and a library is very thin :D I would consider LibGDX and AndEngine not full Game-Engines but Unity or UDK yes.

Comment: @Moss Yeah, it's really very thin that everything is mixing up. In the end, it all depends on how you use the words. Well, I guess I'll have to play smart to get through and try to use AndEngine for it. Thanks a lot guys. :)